# JDBC 4.0 - MS SQL 2005 - how to insert image from Java app?

Tags: java, database, t-sql, jdbc, database-connection

I just downloaded the microsoft jdbc mssql driver to try connect my test app... The lib contains so many methods so I have confused ... There is a BLOB and InputStream can be used but I am not sure which one I need to insert FileInputStream for example? I couldn't find any tutorial showing that, moreover, I want to insert image with t-sql procedure...
So my question is...
How to insert FileInputStream to MS SQL Server 2005 table with Java client app as...

A) With no procedure
B) With t-sql procedure

Any useful tutorial will be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813.aspx) for the JDBC driver, and a similar example [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-store-retrieve-image-to-from-sqlserver-2.html) (found by Googling for "mssql jdbc insert image"). Both of these examples seem to rely on using [setBinaryStream() on a PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) to pass a `FileInputStream` into a BLOB-type field field.

Third example below for reference:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BigTable (Col1) VALUES(?)");
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File("myImg.gif"));
pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, inStream);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
inStream.close();
```

---

In response to question B, I assume that it's possible to create a stored procedure with a BLOB parameter and then pass in an input stream using [CallableStatement#setBinaryStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29) very similar to the above, e.g.,

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{AddImage(?)}");
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File("myImg.gif"));
cstmt.setBinaryStream(1, inStream);
cstmt.executeQuery();
inStream.close();
```

Comment: Thank you :) The second one is look like the jdbc4 but the doc I could find demand to use SQLServerCallableStatement so is there some difference or it is absolutely the same in use?

Comment: `CallableStatement` is the generic JDBC interface. [SQLServerCallableStatement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378161.aspx) is the concrete implementation of that interface for the MS JDBC driver. The only method that leaps out as being defined in `SQLServerCallableStatement` but not in `CallableStatement` is [getDateTimeOffset()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427240.aspx).

Comment: Incidentally, if you follow [Microsoft's examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378956.aspx), you'll generally be working with the generic JDBC classes rather than the SQLServer... versions. To get at the SQLServerCallableStatement, you'd most likely have to do some sort of direct downcasting.

Comment: I have already added the microsoft lib right to use it so I want to make it working... That's why I am interested to know more about it owing to the lib included examples are so less information...